# Funding question for minor in Schengen visa application for Greece

Tags: visa, schengen, greece

I have this probably a silly question but who wants to risk a visa application.

I am applying for a Schengen tourist visa for myself, wife and 4 yo daughter. In the section where they ask about how your travel is funded, I do not see any option for my daughter to say her trip is funded by me. They have three options to question of funding

- Applicant
- Sponsor or host referred in the previous section
- Other sponsor

I was thinking of choosing other sponsor and writing my name over there but just not sure if that will confuse the visa officer.

Anyone has any experience with this?

Comment: I’m not particularly familiar with the application form but why wouldn’t it be ‘sponsor or host referred to in the previous section’? If you’re all applying as a family it should be obvious to an ECO - a 4yo is pretty unlikely to be funding their own travel after all.

Comment: Because the previous section does not refer to me but the hotel that we are staying in.

Comment: Well then the third option is the only one you can choose that is relevant?

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of choosing other sponsor and writing my name over there but just not sure if that will confuse the visa officer.

The "other sponsor" option is the only one that makes sense, and visa officers must surely see such applications all the time.  I don't think it will confuse the officer in the least, and there really isn't anything else you can do to present your circumstances correctly, so it seems that you should indeed do it that way.